# How to make flexible grid css/react

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to `css/react` and I'm looking for a way to make my grids dynamic. The result I want would be a `3 * 3` grids and each of them being dynamically scalable depending on its content. I follow a tutorial but the output wasn't what I was expecting because all of them scale depending on the max size in the `css`.

Here's what I have for the moment.

```css
.container-card {
    margin: auto;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container-item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 300px);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
    grid-gap: 10;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "a a b"
        "a a b"
        "c d d";
    align-content: center;
}
```

```js
function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbars />
            <div className="container-card">
                <div className="container-item">
                    <Cards />
                    <WeatherCards />
                    <OutlookCards />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

and it looks like this.

[image]

Comment: You have **explicitly** told the columns to be 300px wide, that's not responsive or scalable. Use `fr` or % units

Comment: @Paulie_D oh yes I see, but how am I suppose to make it dynamic please ?

Comment: Dynamic how? Please clarify

Comment: @Paulie_D for exemple I would like the middle card to be this size because it's content is this long, but for the spotify and microsoft one, the card should be as long as button width until the user log in, then its size will adapt according to its content